# how to modify python logging module name in formatter

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I've got my python logger configured like this in one of my projects.

Logging from certain modules in subfolders makes the `%(name)s` very long and therefore hard to read the logs. Can I modify the string to only show the actual module name, not the full hierarchy?

**code**

```
import logging
import time

def run():
    logformat = "[%(levelname)s] [%(name)s] %(asctime)s | %(message)s"
    datefmt = "%d-%m %H:%M:%S"

    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(logformat, datefmt=datefmt)



    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(ch)

    for i in range(1, 10):
        time.sleep(1)
        logger.info(f'Waiting {i}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
                    run()
```

**result**

```
[INFO] [root] 21-02 00:19:48 | Waiting 1
[INFO] [root] 21-02 00:19:49 | Waiting 2
...
```

**desired output**

```
[INFO] [ot] 21-02 00:19:48 | Waiting 1
[INFO] [ot] 21-02 00:19:49 | Waiting 2
...
```

Those would be the last 2 characters. It would be even better if I could split that string as in the larger project the `%(name)s` parameter looks like `modules.subfolder.modulename` - I'd like only `modulename`. Is this possible?

Comment: in your format, you're specifying the logger name  [%(name)s] . you can set your logger name to whatever you want, for example logger = logging.getLogger('ot') .

Comment: Great, this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the line in the Python logging code where the message is created from the record. You can simply override this function with your own implementation.

There you can for example split the name of the module and overwrite the name in the dct with the first module level name.

If before `A.B.C` was printed as name, now `A` is printed

```py
import logging

def custom_format(self, record):
    dct = record.__dict__
    dct['name'] = dct['name'].split('.')[0]
    return self._fmt % dct

logging.PercentStyle._format = custom_format
logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)-8s - %(name)s - %(message)s", level='INFO')
```

In your case, you can use:

```py
dct['name'] = dct['name'][-2:]
```